# jekyll-responsive-image not creating new versions of image when the image is edited

Tags: jekyll

I am working on a site using Jekyll and the [jekyll-responsive-image](https://github.com/wildlyinaccurate/jekyll-responsive-image) plugin. The plugin is working great, but I did run into a slight problem that I'm not sure if it is an issue with the plugin or a problem with my configuration.

I added an image to my project, made sure the plugin was working correctly, and then I edited the image. When I refreshed the page, I still saw the old version of the image. I know it is not an issue with my browser caching the old image because I checked the _site folder and the old version of the image was still in there. I had to delete the _site folder in order to get jekyll-responsive-image to reprocess my images.

This seems to be more of an inconvenience than anything, but I am wondering if anyone else has this issue or if my config is just set up incorrectly. Here is a copy of the responsive_image entry in my _config.yml:

```
responsive_image:
  template: _includes/responsive-image.html
  default_quality: 90
  sizes:
    - width: 20
      quality: 10
    - width: 480
      quality: 80
    - width: 800
    - width: 1400
  auto_rotate: false
  strip: true
  base_path: images
  output_path_format: images/resized/%{width}/%{basename}
  save_to_source: false
  cache: false
```